# roslint python errors to stdout?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running roslint within travis like this:

```
catkin build $(catkin list --depends-on roslint -u) --no-deps --catkin-make-args roslint
```

When there is a lint error in C++ it is visible in stdout and is easy to read, but python errors are in a log file like this:

```
Errors     << foo_pkg:make /home/lucasw/catkin_ws/logs/foo_pkg/build.make.472.log
```

Adding `--verbose` works but there is a ton of other output also obscuring the actual error- is there a way to just get the python lint error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335608/roslint-python-errors-to-stdout?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2019-10-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do so by making `pep8` redirect `stdout` to `stderr` with the following in your `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(ROSLINT_PYTHON_OPTS "1>&2")
roslint_python()
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-03-01**:
That works, but it seems like there ought to be a standard option to do that, I looked at the `roslint` pycodestyle.py source and tried out some options but they didn't have any effect when deliberately introducing pep8 violations:

```
set(ROSLINT_PYTHON_OPTS "--show-source")
set(ROSLINT_PYTHON_OPTS "--show-pep8")
set(ROSLINT_PYTHON_OPTS "--verbose")
```

or in combination

```
set(ROSLINT_PYTHON_OPTS "--show-source" "--show-pep8")
```

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-03-01**:
I think the key is to have outputs print to `stderr` which is what `cpplint` does.  However, there doesn't seem to be any option to have `pep8` output to `stderr`.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-08**:
Example of disabling all the default ignores (`E121,E123,E126,E226,E24,E704,W503,W504`):

```
set(ROSLINT_PYTHON_OPTS "--ignore=''" "1>&2")
```